# is there a var_dump like function in clojure?

Tags: clojure, jsoup, ring

I like printf debugging, is there a function in clojure that works like php's var_dump that prints anything it gets?

I'm trying to parse html with jsoup and I'd like to see what I'm doing by printing it as a ring response, in the REPL I see the response as the html file I tried to load, in the browser I see nothing and the terminal show an error: java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized body.

Comment: Show code. Otherwise it is hard to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print to a string, use `pr-str`. Or use `println` to print to the REPL.

```
(pr-str {:a 1}) ;=> "{:a 1}"

(println {:a 1}) ;=> nil  
***REPL contains output***
```

If you want more options and pretty printing, you could try [clojure.pprint](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html) or [fipp](https://github.com/brandonbloom/fipp)

```
(require '[clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]])

(pprint {:a 1}); => nil 
***You can't see it but REPL now contains beautifully formatted output***
```